# Confusing behaviour of EvaluationMonitor in NIntegrate when integrating on a implicit region

Tags: numerical-integration, mesh, monitoring, implicit

I am dealing with some complex integral and I just need an approximate result(have a precision of about 4 digits) for it. Thus I just need to do the integral by sampling at as less points as possible before reaching the prescribed precision. I also need a monitor to see how much it progresses. I have used Mathematica 11 in my calculation. Though the monitor works on the integral of some simple region like in a rectangle(no matter how complicated the function to be integral is), If I make the region to be slightly complex(Though finite), it will cause trouble in using it. Most importantly, in the following code, I have kept the representation of the region the same but only changed the function that determines the boundary a little. All the regions are simply connected and convex. However, the behavior varies. More specific information is written as notes in the following code.

```
Dynamic[k]
(*In the following, f _i is set to determine the boundary of the \
region, while h and g are the function that needs to be calculated, \
one is fast, and the other is slow*)
k = 0;
(*for f, the Evaluation calculator never works, but the integral can be \
carried out. The integral on the bulk has an error estimate, while the \
integral on the surface do not when integrating under RRS4 using h. \
When integrating using RRS2, the integral result can be obtained, but \
an extra error is raised: "DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize \
the region ImplicitRegion[\[LeftSkeleton]2\[RightSkeleton]]"*)
f[kx_, ky_, kz_] := Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2 + Sin[kz]^2
(*for f2, the integral result can not be obtained. Error: "The current \
computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory \
available to complete the computation."*)
f2[kx_, ky_, kz_] := 
 If[-\[Pi]/2 < kx < \[Pi]/2 && -\[Pi]/2 < ky < \[Pi]/2 && -\[Pi]/2 < 
    kz < \[Pi]/2, kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2, 10]
(*f3 works well in every aspect*)
f3[kx_, ky_, kz_] := kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2
(*f4 works similarly with f, even though there is only a single region \
in R^3 satisfied the condition. Moreover, an extra error is raised: \
"DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[\
\[LeftSkeleton]2\[RightSkeleton]]"*)
f4[kx_, ky_, kz_] := 
 kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2 + Sin[kx]^2 + Sin[ky]^2 + Sin[kz]^2
h[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, 
   z_?NumericQ] :=(*designed to be particularly SLOW*)
  Interpolation[Table[{t, Sin[100 t]}, {t, 0, 1, 1./2^10}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][x];
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := x^2;

RR = ImplicitRegion[
   f[kx, ky, kz] < 0.5 && -\[Pi]/2 < kx < \[Pi]/2 && -\[Pi]/2 < 
     ky < \[Pi]/2 && -\[Pi]/2 < kz < \[Pi]/2, {kx, ky, kz}];
RR1 = ImplicitRegion[
   f3[kx, ky, kz] < 0.5 && -\[Pi]/2 < kx < \[Pi]/2 && -\[Pi]/2 < 
     ky < \[Pi]/2 && -\[Pi]/2 < kz < \[Pi]/2, {kx, ky, kz}];
RR2 = ImplicitRegion[
   f[kx, ky, kz] < 
    0.5, {{kx, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {ky, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/
      2}, {kz, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}}];
RRS = ImplicitRegion[f3[kx, ky, kz] == 0.5, {kx, ky, kz}];
RRS2 = ImplicitRegion[
   f[kx, ky, kz] == 0.5 && -\[Pi]/2 < kx < \[Pi]/2 && -\[Pi]/2 < 
     ky < \[Pi]/2 && -\[Pi]/2 < kz < \[Pi]/2, {kx, ky, kz}];
RRS3 = ImplicitRegion[
   f3[kx, ky, kz] == 
    0.5, {{kx, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {ky, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/
      2}, {kz, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}}];
RRS4 = ImplicitRegion[
   f[kx, ky, kz] == 
    0.5, {{kx, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {ky, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/
      2}, {kz, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}}];
RRS5 = ImplicitRegion[f4[kx, ky, kz] == 0.5, {kx, ky, kz}];
(*For RM, EvaluationMonitor does not work, and it seems that \
MaxPoints\[Rule]2000 does not work in this case either*)
RM = DiscretizeRegion[RR1];

(*For SM EvaluationMonitor does not work, and it seems that MaxPoints\
\[Rule]2000 does not work in this case either*)
SM = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RM];

(*Plot the surface mesh using HighlightMesh*)
HighlightMesh[SM, Style[1, Directive[Thick, Red]]]
(*To test other cases, replace \[Element]RRS3 with others*)
NIntegrate[h[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] RRS3, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> k++, MaxPoints -> 2000]
```

If we discretize the region as a mesh, the monitor does not work either, does anyone know what causes this behavior, or any advice on how to integrate over an object with complex geometry where I can see the progress of it? The region I need to deal with is much more complex than the example above, and it worries me that if there is no error estimation, maybe it integrates the result explicitly, and this will cause an unacceptable long time to my real problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reasonable decrease in accuracy and precision helps (in 13.3.1 on Windows 10) as

```
Block[{k = 0}, {NIntegrate[h[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] RRS3, 
AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, EvaluationMonitor :> k++],   k}]
```

> `{-110.85 - 1.3341*10^-7 I, 24308}`

and

```
Block[{k = 0}, {NIntegrate[h[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] RRS3, 
AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6, EvaluationMonitor :> k++], k}]
```

> `{-110.85 - 2.8524*10^-7 I, 60876}`

show.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well for me when integrated over RRS3. However, if you replace it with RRS4, the result will be a warning "DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion" and the monitor does not work in this case. Maybe I should express the problem more clearly and apologize for any confusion. The output will be {-130.014, 0}. I guess that maybe only after the region is discretized can the monitor work well. There are some discussions on the problem "DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion", but the solution circumvents the problem.

Comment: Also, I have tested mesh = DiscretizeRegion[RRS4], and it also works well. This also confused me a lot. I wonder why the message "DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion" appears.

Comment: Having executed `Block[{k = 0}, {NIntegrate[h[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] RRS4, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, EvaluationMonitor :> k++], 
  k}]`, I obtained a warning "DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>]." and `{-131.154, 0}`.

Comment: @zhangyixin: `Block[{k = 0}, {NIntegrate[h[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] RRS,     AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, EvaluationMonitor :> k++],    k}]` works well, performing `{-110.85 - 1.33338*10^-7 I, 13362}`. What are your results with other ones?

Comment: I see, my result is the same as yours. It appears to me that when integrated over RRS and RRS3, it works well just because RR1 and RR3 deal with f3, and f3 is a simple function. However, once my boundary is a little bit complex, such as integrating over RRS4, the evaluator monitor does not work and raises an error of discretize even if it can be discretized if you apply the function
```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[RRS4]
```
I wonder do you have a way to make the evaluation monitor work when doing the integration over RRS4? Thanks